# Identifying Objects

Tags: java, oop, object

**System: Bank Account**

Description: A specific bank would like to develop application for the account system. In the system, there are **customers** who have information such as:

- National_Id
- Name
- Phone
- and address

Each customer can have many accounts. The **account** has the following information

- Account Id
- Balance

There are **four types of accounts**:

- Current_Account
- Checking_Account
- Saving_Account
- and Join_Account.

Each Current_Account will be given a **ATM_CARD** which has

- Card_Number
- and Pin,

each **Checking_Account** will be given **a set of check_book** which has the

- prefix_number
- and amount,

each **Saving_Account** will be given the

- commission

  based on the
- balance
- and company profits

and each **Joint_Account** will have

- list of customers

  who are registered in this account.

Should "Commission" in here be considered as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Commissions are the result of the profits of the bank and its balance.  The way that your requirement reads makes it such that this is more of a method attached to `Saving_Account` instead of an object on its own.

Answer (score 1):

No, commission not need to be an object as it's not having any properties of its own. As in previous comment, just a method which calculates the commission based on account balance and company profit.